# Windows deleting DLL files

Tags: windows, keyboard

I'm using a DLL for hooking keyboard functions. In Windows Server 2000 and Windows 7 it is getting deleted.

Any ideas why it is getting deleted and how to avoid this?

Comment: This question isn't about Visual C++, and correct answers are going to include tools like sysInternals' Process Monitor.  Voting to move to superuser.

Comment: Perhaps it looks like a security threat? Key loggers are popular for capturing confidential data.

Comment: Most probably,anti-virus installed is detecting it as some kind of  threat !!

Answer (score 2):

Probably some virus checker thinking you have a virus. Keyboard hooks are a major security issue. Imagine entering passwords or banking info and having the keyboard hook send the info to another party.

Comment: HI , Thanks for ur reply

whether windows will write any log regarding deletion of files.
If yes please tell me where i can see.

Thank You

Comment: You must have a virus checker on your machine that is doing it, most virus checkers will show you their removed threats. You might be able to configure it to not remove a certain process or a certain folder.

Comment: Windows Defender may have removed it. Defender logs are in Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably,anti-virus installed is detecting it as some kind of threat !!